# Script Python rodar a cada 1 segundo por 3 horas seguidas

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso rodar um script em Python a cada 1 segundo por 3-4 horas por dia.

Esse meu script atualiza os dados em uma tabela, efetua alguns cálculos e toma uma ação caso a regra de cálculo determine.

Apesar de simples, não consegui achar algo nos fóruns que pudesse me ajudar a ter um direcionamento.

Gostaria de algumas sugestões de como poderia fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

Ao meu ver tem duas formas:

1. Loop interno no script

Você pode colocar seu código dentro de um loop com um timer tipo assim:

```py
import time

while True:
    ... seu script aqui
    time.sleep(1)
```

2. Você poderia utilizar o comando "watch" do linux para executar o comando de 1 em 1 segundos, por exemplo:

```bsh
$ watch -n 1 python meuscript.py
```

Comment: Fiz o teste e funcionou para executar o período. Para restringir o período de horas, existe alguma função nessa biblioteca Time?

Comment: Não, mas você pode fazer uma contagem simples de: 3h = 60s * 60m * 3h = 10.800s
E daí colocar mudar um pouco o loop para "while contagem < 10800" e no final dele faz "contagem += 1"

Answer (score 1):

#https://pypi.org/project/APScheduler/

pip install apscheduler

Tente scheduled (agendamento programado)

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

 scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(train_model, 'interval', hours=3)
    scheduler.start()
```

Caso queira criar um meio sem api:

```
import time
import random 

def infinito():
  print("teste")

while True:
    try:
        if infinito() == 1:
            break
    except:
        parada = random.randrange(1, 10)#por um tempo aleatório entre 1-10 ira parar 
        time.sleep(int(parada))
        #time.sleep( parada * 60 )      #a cada minuto ira entrar em um lopp infinito
        pass
```

no 60 troque por minutos a hora ou dias